# gae - is it possible to divide the app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, share, datastore

Is it possible to design the app on gae in that way
- admin part - gwt, guice
- user part - guice, html, js

They should be independent for performance reason. As I know the app can be started on each request so there is no reason to launch and load admin part into memory every  time.
As I've read it's not possible to share datastore between 2 apps. Maybe guice supports such scenario ?

Edit

sorry I'll try again

1. I found that the app can be restarted for each http request. Even for the same user and the same session
2. It takes a few precious seconds to start the app
3. Part of the app is rarely used, it would be written in gwt, would be rather heavy and used only by administrators
   I thought that I could save some time here - on guice injection, class initialization etc. But maybe I'm wrong couse all the resources
   are created on demand and there is no problem.
   I've just don't know guice and gwt yet

Comment: Why should they be independent for performance reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about lazy creation of beans. It is so by default (unless you are using toInstance binding):

```
package com.sopovs.moradanen;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Creating injector");
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
    System.out.println("Injector created");
    System.out.println("Getting instance of Foo");
    injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
    System.out.println("Got instance of Foo");

    System.out.println("Getting instance of Bar");
    injector.getInstance(Bar.class);
    System.out.println("Got instance of Bar");

    System.out.println("Getting another instance of Foo");
    injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
    System.out.println("Got another instance of Foor");
}

@Singleton
public static class Foo {

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo Created");
    }
}

@Singleton
public static class Bar {

    public Bar() {
        System.out.println("Bar Created");
    }
}
}
```

Output is:

```
Creating injector
Injector created
Getting instance of Foo
Foo Created
Got instance of Foo
Getting instance of Bar
Bar Created
Got instance of Bar
Getting another instance of Foo
Got another instance of Foor
```